# Asymptotic complexity of exponential function multiplied by logarithm and factorial.

Tags: asymptotics

I got this two functions to compare in preparation for a test:

$$
2^n \cdot \ln(n^2)
$$

and

$$
2\cdot n!+4\cdot n^2.
$$

I know that second function I can count as if it was just $n!$. But I still don't know which of these functions grow faster...

Can someone help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: You try to compare it with the intermediate $3^n$ for example